# Overlap Imageview in bottomsheetfragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Im trying to achieve an effect like this on a bottomSheetFragment where the Imageview overlaps on-top of the BottomSheetFragment.
I tried to constrain the image view to the top of the card view set a margin then make the background of the layout transparent

[image: [1]]

But this is how it comes out when i run it

[image: [2]]

This is my XML attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

tools:context=".ui.generalviews.SuccessBottomSheetFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
   >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/successicon"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/buenosairesweb_light"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="₦5,000.00"
            android:textColor="#242C37"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/buenosaires2web_bold"
            android:text="john oladr"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/buenosairesweb_light"
            android:text="428948929 "
            android:textColor="#242C37"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView122"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/successicon"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/card"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code and just by looking at your images it looks like you have not anchored your view to bottomsheet. Add below properties to your tick view.

```
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"
```

you would need to use `CoordinatorLayout` to use this.

also you are using `ImageView` use `FloatingActionButton`. replace your Image with below code and try.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView122"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/successicon"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"/>
```

if you want to continue with `ImageView` provide some elevation as cardview will be having some elevation by default.

Comment: Do i add this to the BottomSheet layout?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried that but it doesn't seem to display again. i posted my code.

Comment: Remove empty coordinator layout you have added and replace make your parent layout to `CoordinatorLayout` from `ConstraintLayout` currently you are using constratint layout, both are different.

Comment: I did that but the tick still doesn't display edited my code accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the help again, I did that the result is in the update. I think i am suppose to do this in the layout that displays the Bottom Sheet but the problem is how do i reference the Bottom Sheet from that layout since it a Modal Bottom Sheet

Comment: @BoluOkunaiya are you including this as a separate layout to your main layout?

Comment: if you are including bottom sheet with separate layout you can assign id to layout you include, add this this image to your main layout and use id that you assigned to `<include>`